# Why is this WordPress mysql query so much faster? (aka explaining Explain)

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Can anyone help me understand why the second query is so much faster?

This is from a WordPress database where wp_posts is a table with columns `ID, post_title, post_status...` and wp_postmeta is a table with columns `ID, post_id, meta_key, meta_value`. wp_posts.ID corresponds to wp_postmeta.post_id.

I've looked at the output of Explain but it isn't clear to me. I see that the query executes in a slightly different order but I don't really understand why it changed the order or why it would be so much faster.

I'd really like to understand so I know if it's applicable to other queries.

Thanks!

---

### Query 1:: ~14sec

```
SELECT
    COALESCE( SUM( wpm1.meta_value ), 0  ) as package_sum,
    wpm2.meta_value as prp_id
FROM wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta wpm1 ON wpm1.post_id = wp_posts.ID
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta wpm2 ON wpm2.post_id = wp_posts.ID
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta wpm3 ON wpm3.post_id = wp_posts.ID
WHERE post_type='voucher'
AND post_status IN ( 'requested', 'disputed', 'issued', 'visit-required', 'claimed', 'witheld', 'approved', 'paid' )
AND wpm1.meta_key='voucher_value'
AND wpm2.meta_key='prp'
AND wpm3.meta_key='supplier'
AND wpm3.meta_value='955'
GROUP BY wpm2.meta_value

EXPLAIN:
-----------------------
id   select_type     table       type        possible_keys               key         key_len     ref                     rows    filtered    Extra
1    SIMPLE          wpm2        ref         post_id,meta_key            meta_key    767         const                   80212   100.00      Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1    SIMPLE          wp_posts    eq_ref      PRIMARY,type_status_date    PRIMARY     8           gigabit.wpm2.post_id    1       100.00      Using where
1    SIMPLE          wpm3        ref         post_id,meta_key            post_id     8           gigabit.wpm2.post_id    50      100.00      Using where
1    SIMPLE          wpm1        ref         post_id,meta_key            post_id     8           gigabit.wpm2.post_id    50      100.00      Using where
```

---

### Query 2:: ~3.0sec

```
SELECT
    COALESCE( SUM( wpm1.meta_value ), 0  ) as package_sum,
    wpm2.meta_value as prp_id
FROM wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta wpm1 ON wpm1.post_id = wp_posts.ID AND wpm1.meta_key='voucher_value'
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta wpm2 ON wpm2.post_id = wp_posts.ID AND wpm2.meta_key='prp'
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta wpm3 ON wpm3.post_id = wp_posts.ID AND wpm3.meta_key='supplier'
WHERE post_type='voucher'
AND post_status IN ( 'requested', 'disputed', 'issued', 'visit-required', 'claimed', 'witheld', 'approved', 'paid' )
AND wpm3.meta_value='955'
GROUP BY wpm2.meta_value

EXPLAIN:
-----------------------
id   select_type     table       type        possible_keys               key         key_len     ref                     rows    filtered    Extra
1    SIMPLE          wpm3        ref         post_id,meta_key            meta_key    767         const                   71970   100.00      Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1    SIMPLE          wp_posts    eq_ref      PRIMARY,type_status_date    PRIMARY     8           gigabit.wpm3.post_id    1       100.00      Using where
1    SIMPLE          wpm1        ref         post_id,meta_key            post_id     8           gigabit.wpm3.post_id    50      100.00      Using where
1    SIMPLE          wpm2        ref         post_id,meta_key            post_id     8           gigabit.wpm3.post_id    50      100.00      Using where
```

Comment: The difference between the queries is that you've moved the 'AND wpmX.meta_key' clauses into the LEFT JOIN ON? Does this make the same difference if you use regular JOINs, not LEFT JOINs? Not that should really matter, but if you weren't checking for a non-null value in a left-joined column then you are potentially asking for different things.